# Updating entity does not work in entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have migrated my project from EF4 to EF6. I am facing trouble while updating the records. Below is my code

```
public int SaveApplicantData(Applicant objApplicant, bool isEdit)
    {
        DBEntities context = new DBEntities();
        int applicantId = 0;
        try
        {

                if (objApplicant.Id > 0)
                {
                  var applicant = context.Applicants.Where(a => ((a.Id != objApplicant.Id) && (a.SSN == objApplicant.SSN))).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (applicant != null)
                    {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        applicant = context.Applicants.Find(objApplicant.Id);
                    }
                   if (applicant != null)
                    {
                        applicant.FirstName = "TEST NAME";
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                return objApplicant.Id;
            }
        }
```

I have also tried `context.Entry(applicant).CurrentValues.SetValues(objApplicant)` but does not work for me. Spending lot of hours in finding solution. Please assists with appropriate solution.

**UPDATE**

Also I tried

```
  context.Applicants.Attach(objApplicant);
  context.Entry(objApplicant).State = EntityState.Modified;
  context.SaveChanges();
```

but no success!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code instead of adding in `context.Applicants.Add(objApplicant);`

```
 context.Entry(objApplicant).State = EntityState.Modified;
 context.SaveChanges();
```

**Update**:  Try this code block.

```
                if (applicant != null)
                {
                    applicant.FirstName = "TEST NAME";
                    context.Entry(applicant).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
```

Comment: After doing this I got exception **Attaching an entity of type 'FlexPath.Entity.Entities.Applicant' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value**

Comment: No any error message after your implementation but values are not updating in database.

Comment: Check the connection string, copy paste the connection string to your UI /Web config

Comment: you are using DbContext or ObjectContext ?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. There was no issues with the queries. It was with database sql server azure where columns are not updating if triggers are present on that table.

Comment: You can update  records, unless there is some exception with your trigger.